# What is the purpose of a debrief meeting before an event?

Tags: word-usage

I recently received an invite for a *debrief* meeting for an event in the future, to inform us about the proceedings of the event. I was a bit confused since I am acquainted with such debriefs being conducted *after* an event e.g. in the usual espionage terms wherein people are questioned *after* missions. I had expected the meeting to be a *briefing* session rather than a *de*briefing session. Is there another connotation to the word debrief that suits this scenario or is it fine to use the word here or is this incorrect usage?

Comment: The use of *debriefing* was merely careless: it was a slipshod back-extension of meaning from the proper backward-looking use of *debriefing* (as you mention), to apply to the forward-looking use of *briefing*. When we have two similar words that mean different things, it is foolish to apply one of them carelessly to both things.

Comment: It could be the "debrief" was meant to be a "prebrief".

Comment: It would be a briefing. It's either a typo or the sender doesn't know the difference. I wouldn't rule out either possibility.

Comment: It sounds like a preliminary brainwashing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Outstanding intuition there. Also, just an example of the opposite word used: infer instead of imply, literally for figuratively, adopt for adapt, and the au courant conversate and orientate for I forgot what.

Comment: I'm curious as to how may I improve the question since it's elicited a -1. I didn't find any relevant answers on this site. I had searched for the meanings of debriefing but didn't find any that suited the context. I've mentioned why I find its usage strange. What else should be done before posting a question?

Comment: Not sure why it's voted down or remains unanswered, but it might hypothetically be because it's answerable by looking up "debrief" in a dictionary, because it's viewed as a rant against people misusing words rather than being a serious question, or because you basically answered your own question and just want a bit of reassurance. It's not unusual for people to misuse language, especially if they're not professional writers in an edited publication.

Comment: Ah ok. No, it wasn't certainly a rant but more on whether there's some valid use in the context that I mentioned. I think I've received the _reasssurance_ that my intuition was indeed right. Since this wasn't a one-off event of the meeting organizer using the word, I thought of eliciting the community's response, but I can certainly see your point on why the question might have been perceived otherwise.